# Strange syntax error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

Why does this give me an MySQL syntax error:

```
<cfset arguments.where = "platformUrlId='#params.platformUrlId#'">

SELECT *
FROM whatever
WHERE #arguments.where#
Order By #arguments.order#
```

But this works perfectly well?

```
<cfset arguments.where = "0=0">

SELECT *
FROM whatever
WHERE #arguments.where#
Order By #arguments.order#
```

It's not my param because I dumped the param next to a twin that I typed out, and they match... passing the string directly works, but setting the string in an argument then using the argument breaks it

**EDIT: The error output is showing `platformUrlId=''playstation3''`** Coldufsion is adding `''` around the argument name. How come?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `ORDER BY` in there, instead of `ORDER`?

Comment: Daniel, sorry, I didn't copy/paste. I typed that part out; my code does say ORDER BY

Comment: That's fantastic question, pardon my french. No SQL query, nor error message. And after all not even a real code but quick hand-drawn draft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prevent problems when your variable contians someting like "Dexy's Midnight Runniers", CF implicitly escapes single quotes in CFQuery.  You can prevent this by using preserveSingleQuotes().

However, what you are doing is definitely not a recommended practice.  If you need to write this as a function, I'd do something more along the lines of passing in an array of key/value pairs, and using cfQueryParam to prevent any SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably better make use of the [cfqueryparam](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/6.1/htmldocs/tags-b20.htm) tag like this:

```
<cfquery>
  SELECT *
  FROM tbl 
  WHERE #arguments.colname# = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.platformUrlId#"> 
  ORDER BY #arguments.order#
</cfquery>
```